# The how to run function in input set that need to have ViewChild value?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to invoke function after `ngAfterViewInit` in `Input()` `set`?

I have a div:

template:  `<div #myDiv> </div>`

and I want to run some third party function that do some logic on this `div`. the problem is when set is invoke the `div` is `undefined` and only in ngAfterViewInit is initialized.

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv;

@Input set value(val) {
  this.run(val); // <--- first run
}

run(val) { 
 console.log({ myDiv: this.myDiv }); // <--- undefined 

 someLib({ // this is the function I can't change.
  div: this.myDiv.nativeElement
 });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
 console.log({ myDiv: this.myDiv }); // <-- initialized
}
```

I need when the value change to invoke the `run` function. Maybe is there a similar `nextTick` like vue have?

Comment: you can use ngOnChanges() ,so whenever there is any change in input properties this lifecycle method will call

Comment: store the set value in some local variable _set kind of this and once ui initialised in ngAfterViewInit() call the run method by passing the _set variable